# Configure Firebase max requests from client (FirebaseTooManyRequestsException)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

I use Firebase Auth with Phone in my application. This kind of auth provides sending sms to a user with code to be entered.

I wonder if there a way to configure how much sms could be sent to a particular user at time period.

I know that there is [FirebaseTooManyRequestsException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) which means that the server handles such situations, but I want to limit the user by my own rules.

Answer (score 1):

See [phone_number_sign-in_limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#phone_number_sign-in_limits). If you want to change limit then you should [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).